# What is the asynchronous reads?

Tags: c

What is the asynchronous reads in disk?  I konw that synchronous reads is accessed by a single thread, and it like sequentical reads, but what is asynchronous reads?  Thanks!

Comment: It's homework!  What does the textbook say?

Comment: google yields plenty of results.

Comment: You just asked this a few hours ago.

Comment: Re the "on-hold", I can't see that this is about general computing hardware and software at all. in what Bizarro universe would an Excel spreadsheet zombie or Word-wielding letter-writer ever had a need to ask about async reads? Voting to re-open :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asynchronous *anything* is something that happens side-by-side with whatever else you're doing.

Hence, with a synchronous read, you do the following:

- issue a read command to the operating system.
- wait until it's finished.
- retrieve the data.

A asynchronous read tends to be more like this:

- issue an async read to the operating system.
- continue with some other task (rendering graphics, calculating pi, etc).
- get notified that the read is finished.
- finish whatever you were doing, if necessary.
- retrieve the data.

Some operating systems provide their own facilities to do async reads (and writes for that matter), where the OS simply creates a separate thread of execution to do the work then notify you.

Even if the OS doesn't give you that, you can do it yourself with threads and inter-thread communication methods such as condition variables.

Comment: I have another questions from your answer. Who issue a read command to the file system and wait until it's finished. Is it CPU? in,•go do the dishes. What does the dishes mean?   Thank you!

Comment: @user3464179: "go do the dishes" is just a placeholder for whatever other thing your program is meant to be doing. "Doing the dishes" is washing and drying them after a meal. I'll change it to something a little less culturally specific. In terms of who issues the read, it's the OS itself. It will start a new thread (or have an old thread just lying around for such a purpose) to do the read and then notify your thread that asked for the async read. All invisible to you of course.

Comment: Thanks!  I still not very clear about why asynchronous reads are faster? Is it just because CPU can do some other things when it waits for disking reading completing?

Comment: _Seemingly_ faster from a user's point of view. The fact that there's some _other_ thread of execution waiting means that _your_ code can continue to do other stuff in the meantime. If you have no other stuff to do, you may as well stay synchronous but that's rarely the case nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! Is it same between "OS issues a read command to the operating system", and CPU issues a read command to the operating system"?  My friends told me that CPU issue a read command to the operating system.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3464179, generally a _program_ issues commands to the OS, the OS issues commands to the "disk". There may be a lot more levels involved but that illustrates the direction.